# What can I call her, or whom can I call her?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

In the case of asking what to address someone, which form is grammatical: "What can I call him?" Or "Whom can I call him?"?

Comment: You may ask "How does he like to be addressed?"  Another way is to start formal and let others say "Oh, call me Pat."

Comment: “What does he like to be called?” is another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct phrasing would be 'What should I call him?' or 'By what title should I address him?' where the corresponding answer could be 'Doctor. Doctor Marx.'

The use case for whom would be 'To whom should I address this invitation?' where the corresponding answer might be 'Please address it to His Majesty, Prince Henry.'